# Resize column and text on grid using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am still new in Xaml and WPF. I am trying to create a user control which contains a grid. From on the one hand it will start with a fixed position, but the user with a grid spliter can resize the column.

I am not sure how to that. In the code I wrote below the user can change the column but the text is changing with the column.

I hope for a solution, thanks.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="TBDatanTime" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DataAndTime }" ></TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBComPort" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White"  Text="{Binding ComPort }" ></TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBTranslation" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Translation }" ></TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBTLV" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="6" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Node_ID }" ></TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TLV_INFO" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="8" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TLV_INFO }" ></TextBlock>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="9" Width="1"></GridSplitter>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TBDataBytesArray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="10" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Data_ARR }" ></TextBlock>            
       </Grid>
```

Comment: It's not realy clear what you want. Do you want to resize the `TextBlock` or not? And what about the fontsize?

Comment: just want to resize the textblocks. or the text inside the textblocks

Comment: *"want to resize the textblocks"* - then remove `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` from them.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want either, but if you want to resize the columns you probably will have to set the VerticalAlignment="Stretch" and HorizontalAlignment="Left" (or Right) iin the GridSplitter element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the `TextBlock` to resize with the columns and have the font size resize as well. To do that you will need to use events. Ideally you would want to use a `SizeChanged` event on each of the `ColumnDefinition`, but they don't have that event.

Best solution I can think of is to add these events to the `Grid`:

```
<Grid Name="grid" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp">
```

Since `GridSplitter` works by clicking and dragging, these events will essentially capture that. Now in your code, handle these events

```
// Activates when the mouse is down
private bool drag = false;

public void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // activate the drag
    drag = true;
}

public void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // deactivate the drag
    drag = false;
}

public void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // check if the mouse is down
    if(drag)
    {
         // loop through each of your textblocks and change their width and text if necessary
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.Children.Count; i += 2)
        {
             // access the textblock
             TextBlock textblock = grid.Children[i];
             // set the width to the width of the column it's in
             textblock.Width = grid.ColumnDefinitions(Grid.GetColumn(textblock)).ActualWidth;
             // if you want to change the font size...
             textblock.FontSize = 12;
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure you set the `TextBlock` alignment to Left. Hope this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Remove the properties which are not needed for an example about how to use `GridSplitter`.

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                Text="DataAndTime" />
     <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                   Width="1"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" 
                Text="ComPort" />
     <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3"
                   Width="1"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"  
                Text="Translation" />
     <GridSplitter Grid.Column="5"
                   Width="1"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" 
                Text="Node_ID" />
     <GridSplitter Grid.Column="7" 
                   Width="1"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="8"  
                Text="TLV_INFO" />
     <GridSplitter Grid.Column="9"
                   Width="1"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="10"  
                Text="Data_ARR" />
 </Grid>
```

Important for you:

- When you set the `ColumnDefinition` to `*` the resize behavior will change; just try it to know what I'm talking about. That's why I set the width=100.
- Remove the `Grid.Row="1"` from your `GridSplitter` because you just have one row in the `Grid`you've posted.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: the text is bounded to a list for describe the test.

Comment: And why is this interesting for the `GridSplitter` part? ;)